# Как перехватить исключения разных типов с помощью одного блока except?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Правильно ли `except ErrorA or ErrorB:`

Comment: `except(ErrorA, ErrorB):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы перехватывать исключения, типы которых не связаны общей иерархией, запишите их названия в скобках через запятую.

```
try:
    # ... какой-то код ...
except (TypeError, IndexError, ZeroDivisionError) as err:
    # обработка исключения типа TypeError, IndexError либо ZeroDivisionError
# исключения всех прочих типов* будут переданы далее по коду
```

<sup>* которые не являются производными от вышеуказанных</sup>

Часть `as err` не является обязательной, это лишь позволяет обратиться к объекту исключения, чтобы получить дополнительную информацию об ошибке.

Чуть подробнее с синтаксисом исключений можно ознакомиться во встроенной документации по команде `pydoc except` (ввести в терминал; в системах, основанных на Debian нужно писать `pydoc3 except`). Или прямо из Python вызвать функцию `help("except")` для получения справки.